# Android Studio: How to quickly move styling from layout.xml to style.xml?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-styles

*Code Block 1*: I have the below code in **view.xml**

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#00FF00"
    android:typeface="monospace"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
```

*Code Block 2*: Now I want to move it to a styling like this.

```
<TextView
    style="@style/CodeFont"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
```

*Code Block 3*: In my **styles.xml** file, I want to have this.

```
<resources>
    <style name="CodeFont" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Wrapping all those attributes in an `<item name="XXX"/>` tag is a very manual and annoying process. Does Android Studio have some type of wizardry to automatically convert the attributes from code block 1 into the item tags from code block 3?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

While editing your `TextView` (inside the layout `.xml` file) press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and type `extract`. The item you need is `Style...`.

Comment: Android Studio 2+ : `Refactor > Extract > Style...`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works! I had a lot of code to be refactored and found this just in time.

Comment: Try selecting the Layout Item not the attributes

Comment: works for android: not app: attributes, which is not ideal